# eth_signTypedData does not exist

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

with any web3 or ethers provider I am getting this error.
This is suddently startedoccuring. Noticed it when my hardhat test cases started failing.

Is anyone else facing the same and has solution??

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: You have to provide much more details. What are you doing when you get this error exactly? Include code.